# React - Service call being called 3 times and not passing props correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I am writing creating a webapp with React and redux using react hooks. I created a `service` that wil sue axios to make a all to an external api and bring back some data. That data is then plugged into the `Redux Store` and the components `state` then passed to a child component through `props`.

The problem im facing is A.) The parent component seems to be loading 3 times & B.) The timing is as follows through the `console output`:

```
reducer process time: 0.14
overview data {}
props undefined
overview data {accessibility: {…}, qa: {…}, seo: {…}, total: 88.52, _links: {…}}
SET_DASHBOARD_OVERVIEW
dispatching {type: "SET_DASHBOARD_OVERVIEW", webDashboard: {…}}
reducer process time: 0.03
next state {settings: Array(0), webDashboard: Array(1)}
overview data {accessibility: {…}, qa: {…}, seo: {…}, total: 88.52, _links: {…}}
```

I know this is a timing issue that when the parent/child components load the call hasnt been made for the data and in such there is no data to pass down through props. Im struggling trying to figure out how to get this working so the aprent will load, make the call, get the data, pass the data to the child.

**Service.js**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const moment = require('moment');

const siteImproveUrl = 'https://api.siteimprove.com/v2/sites/*******';

const authStr = '***********';

const getOverview = axios
    .get(siteImproveUrl + '/dci/overview', {params: {}, headers: {'Authorization': authStr}})
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(error => {
        if(error.response) {
            return error.reponse
        }
    });

module.exports = {
    getOverview
};
```

**Dashboard.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import QuickAnalytics from './quickAnalytics';
import TotalVisits from './totalVisits';
import PageRankings from './pageRankings';
import VisitsByHour from './visitsByHour';
import VisitLast30Days from './visitsLast30Days';

import 'chartist/dist/chartist';
import 'chartist/dist/chartist.min.css';

import './visitsByTime.scss';

import store from '../../../Redux/Store/store';
import { setDashboardOverview } from '../../../Redux/Actions/Actions';

const { getOverview } = require('../../../Util/Service');

const WebsiteDashboard = () => {
    const [overviewData, setOverviewData] = useState({});
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    async function fetchData() {
        getOverview.then(result => {
            try {
                setLoading(true);
                setOverviewData(result);
                store.dispatch(setDashboardOverview({overview: overviewData}));
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e); //TODO: Add Toast service
            } finally {
                setLoading(false);
            }
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(loading) {
            fetchData();
        }
    }, [loading]);

    console.log('overview data',overviewData);

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col">
                    <div className="card-chart card">
                        <div className="card-header">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="text-left col-sm-6">
                                    <h5 className="card-category">Website Admin</h5>
                                    <h3 className="card-title">Dashboard</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="text-left col-12">
                                    <QuickAnalytics overviewData={overviewData.qa}/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="card-chart card">
                        <div className="card-header">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="text-left col-sm-6">
                                    <h5 className="card-category">Total Visits Today</h5>
                                    <h3 className="card-title">Total: 6,550</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="text-left col-12">
                                    <TotalVisits />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <div className="card-chart card">
                        <div className="card-header">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="text-left col-sm-6">
                                    <h5 className="card-category">Top 5 pages</h5>
                                    <h3 className="card-title">As of: 06/26/20</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="text-left col-12">
                                    <PageRankings />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="card-chart card">
                        <div className="card-header">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="text-left col-sm-6">
                                    <h5 className="card-category">Visits By Hour</h5>
                                    <h3 className="card-title">Total Page Visits: 34,890</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="text-left col-12">
                                    <VisitsByHour />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="card-chart card">
                        <div className="card-header">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="text-left col-sm-6">
                                    <h5 className="card-category">Visits In The Last 30 Days</h5>
                                    <h3 className="card-title">Total Page Visits: 434,890</h3>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="text-left col-12">
                                    <VisitLast30Days />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default connect()(WebsiteDashboard);
```

**quickAnalytics.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist';

import './pieChart.scss';

let QA_data = {
    series: [80, 20]
};
let ADA_data = {
    series: [65, 35]
};
let SEO_data = {
    series: [50, 50]
};
let sum = function (a, b) { return a + b };

export default class QuickAnalytics extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log('props', props.overviewData);
        this.state = {
            data: props.overviewData
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row d-flex align-items-md-center mx-auto">
                    <div className="col text-center"> 
                        <div className="pieChart">
                            <h4>Site Improve QA</h4>
                            <ChartistGraph data={QA_data} options={
                                {
                                    labelInterpolationFnc: function (value) {
                                        return Math.round(value / QA_data.series.reduce(sum) * 100) + '%';
                                    },
                                    donut: true,
                                    donutWidth: 25,
                                    donutSolid: true,
                                    showLabel: true
                                }} type={'Pie'} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col text-center">
                        <div className="pieChart">
                            <h4>ADA Accessibility</h4>
                            <ChartistGraph data={ADA_data} options={
                                {
                                    labelInterpolationFnc: function (value) {
                                        return Math.round(value / ADA_data.series.reduce(sum) * 100) + '%';
                                    },
                                    donut: true,
                                    donutWidth: 25,
                                    donutSolid: true,
                                    showLabel: true
                                }} type={'Pie'} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col text-center">
                        <div className="pieChart">
                            <h4>SEO</h4>
                            <ChartistGraph data={SEO_data} options={
                                {
                                    labelInterpolationFnc: function (value) {
                                        return Math.round(value / SEO_data.series.reduce(sum) * 100) + '%';
                                    },
                                    donut: true,
                                    donutWidth: 25,
                                    donutSolid: true,
                                    showLabel: true
                                }} type={'Pie'} />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by adding a conditional loading around the child component:

```
{loading ? (
    <div> Loading...</div>
) : (
    <QuickAnalytics overviewData={overviewData.qa} />
)}
```